# Must all functionals be integrals and all path integrals over functions of functionals?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics

I have two related questions:

1. <strike>Can you have a functional, $s[x(t)]$, which is not an integral?</strike> (I think a function of a functional is still a functional) Can you have a functional that has $x(t)$ not within an integral (or placed within an integral)?
2. Can you have a (Feynman) path integral $\int \mathscr{D}[x(\tau)] $ over a function which is not a function of a functional?

**Reason Why I ask**

The standard way of explaining path integrals is to split the path into $N$ segments and then take the limit as $N\rightarrow \infty$. That means we must be able to write:
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\int dx_1...dx_N f(x_1,...,x_N)$$
my confusion arises of what happens to $f(x_1,...,x_N)$ as $N\rightarrow \infty$. It must depend on the curve $x(\tau)$ but I am unsure of what forms this dependency takes.

Comment: It would help if you clarified some definitions.   What is your definition of a "functional"? Not that "non-linear functionals" are not a part of "functional analysis", which is one of the tags you've chosen.  Also, can you be more precise with what you mean when to say "$s[x(t)]$ is an integral"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom For the definition - what ever is standard in this context. By $s[x(t)]$ an integral I mean that: $s[x(t)]=\int f(x(t))dt$ for some function $f$

Comment: 1. $s[x] := x(0)$ is a functional for all functions $x∈C[ℝ]$.

Comment: And $s[x] = x(0)$ is an integral with respect to a point-mass measure.  Will Quantum include "integrals" with respect to Schwarz distributions as well?

Comment: @GEdgar True. I just thought about scalar products or norms, but they can be seen as integrals as well.

Comment: @P.Siehr For the sake of argument, I would probably say that $s[x]=x(0)$ constitute an integral. See my edit above.

Comment: @GEdgar See my comment and edit above.